# Category page custom filed filter to display product

Tags: magento2

I add custom filter like "in stock" in category page.
I create plugin afterSetCollection(), beforeSetCollection(), aroundSetCollection().
and create join for get custom field called count which is i get from my custom table.
i use all references but not working.

[image]

The in stock product count is show first and out of stock product show at last.
i want to show it like in stock to out of stock sorting .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to add a custom filter for products that are in stock on the category page in Magento 2. To do this, you can create a plugin for the Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct block and use the afterSetCollection, beforeSetCollection, or aroundSetCollection methods to modify the product collection.

Here is an example of how you can use the afterSetCollection method to add a filter for in-stock products:

Create a di.xml file in your module's etc directory with the following contents:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="in_stock_filter" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\InStockFilter"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Create the InStockFilter plugin class with the following contents:

   ```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

    use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

    class InStockFilter
    {
        /**
         * @var ResourceConnection
         */
        protected $resourceConnection;

        public function __construct(ResourceConnection $resourceConnection)
        {
            $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        }

        public function afterSetCollection(ListProduct $subject, $result)
        {
            $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
            $select = $connection->select()
                ->from(['stock' => $connection->getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item')], ['product_id', 'count' => 'SUM(stock.qty)'])
                ->group('stock.product_id')
                ->where('stock.is_in_stock = ?', 1);

            $result->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(['stock' => $select], 'e.entity_id = stock.product_id', [])
                ->where('stock.count > ?', 0);

            return $result;
        }
    }
   ```

In this example, we create a left join between the product collection and a subquery that selects the product IDs and the sum of the quantity of in-stock items for each product from the cataloginventory_stock_item table. Then we add a filter to the product collection to only include products with a stock count greater than 0.

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: Which Magento2 version you are using ?

Comment: version : Magento 2.4.5

Comment: ok so are out of stock products showing last forever ? my code is working or not in that case ? I mean my code is filtering data but products is showing at last always ?

Comment: i find the solution now. thank you for your valuable response Sir.

Comment: Okay, thank you